# iPhone json parsing problem

Tags: iphone, json

When I try to parse ( http://www.roundmenu.com/webservices/index.cfm?ws=listrst&filter=featured ) webservice in json I encounter issues.

If any one can find out what the problem please let me know.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s not valid JSON. As usual, it’s useful to validate JSON input via http://jsonlint.com.

That particular JSON input fails to properly escape double quotes (`\"`) inside strings.

Answer (score 2):

Put the response in a json formatter like [this one on curiousconcept.com](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter). It yields many errors, does look like it's invalid json.